# Unable to configure Hazelcast clustering at openfire server

Tags: openfire

I am trying to setup Hazelcast cluster in my LAN. There are two open fire server openfire1 and openfire2 behind a HAProxy sharing a common db server.

I have installed and configured open fire and hazelcast on both. Now when I see from Openfire Admin Console in the clustering section: My openfire1 is not listing the other node in cluster. openfire2 also does not allow me to enable cluster,whenever I see the error I see following log:

```
2014.12.06 12:12:46 com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCacheFactory - Failed to execute cluster task within 30 seconds
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.resolveResponse(Invocati onImpl.java:466)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java: 314)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.DelegatingFuture.get(DelegatingFuture.java:66)
at com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCacheFactory.doSynchronousClusterTask(Clus teredCacheFactory.java:334)
at org.jivesoftware.util.cache.CacheFactory.doSynchronousClusterTask(CacheFactory. java:586)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.system_002dclustering_jsp._jspService(system_00 2dclustering_jsp.java:123)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1359)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:11 8)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1330)
at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1330)
at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingF ilter.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.ja va:1330)
at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:78)
```

Plz tell me if i am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

now i have overcome this problem only by using the correct version of hazlecast.jar corresponding to openfire 3.9.3 ;The Hazelcast plugin version corresponding to the Openfire release (3.9.3) is 1.2.0 .

Direct link to download : https://community.igniterealtime.org/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.igniterealtime.org%2Fprojects%2Fopenfire%2Fplugins-dev%2Fhazelcast.jar